# WCF There was no channel that could accept the message with action

Tags: wcf, wcf-client

I am getting this error message. There was no channel that could accept the message with action.

`'http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/transfer/Get'.`

I have the trace enabled on the Service and from the log I got this.

My Server config is:

```
<system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
   <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="DCTTPIEngine.TPIWCFServiceBehavior">
     <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
     <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false" />
      <dataContractSerializer maxItemsInObjectGraph="2147483647"/>
    </behavior>
   </serviceBehaviors>
  </behaviors>
  <services>
   <service behaviorConfiguration="DCTTPIEngine.TPIWCFServiceBehavior"
    name="DCTTPIEngine.ServiceModel.TPI.XmlMessageService">
    <endpoint address="http://ws-lds-020:8080/DCTTPIEngine/TPIEngine" binding="wsHttpBinding" name="endPoint1"
     contract="DCTTPIEngine.ServiceModel.TPI.XmlServiceInterface" />
    <endpoint address="http://ws-lds-020:8080/DCTTPIEngine/TPIEngine/mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" name="MexEndPoint"
     contract="IMetadataExchange" />
    <host>
     <baseAddresses>
      <add baseAddress="http://ws-lds-020:8080/DCTTPIEngine/TPIEngine" />
     </baseAddresses>
    </host>
   </service>
  </services>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

And my Client config is :

```
 <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface" closeTimeout="00:01:00"
            openTimeout="00:01:00" receiveTimeout="00:10:00" sendTimeout="00:01:00"
            bypassProxyOnLocal="false" transactionFlow="false" hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
            maxBufferPoolSize="524288" maxReceivedMessageSize="65536"
            messageEncoding="Text" textEncoding="utf-8" useDefaultWebProxy="true"
            allowCookies="false">
          <readerQuotas maxDepth="32" maxStringContentLength="8192" maxArrayLength="16384"
              maxBytesPerRead="4096" maxNameTableCharCount="16384" />
          <reliableSession ordered="true" inactivityTimeout="00:10:00"
              enabled="false" />
          <security mode="Message">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" proxyCredentialType="None"
                realm="" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Windows" negotiateServiceCredential="true"
                algorithmSuite="Default" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://ws-lds-020:8080/DCTTPIEngine/TPIEngine"
          binding="wsHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface"
          contract="XmlServiceInterface" name="WSHttpBinding_XmlServiceInterface">
        <identity>
          <userPrincipalName value="bahadur.shaik@minorplanet.local" />
        </identity>
      </endpoint>
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Can anyone please help me?  I tried looking at this problem.

Comment: How is your WCF service hosted? How are you trying to access the WCF service? Dont you have a .svc file?

Comment: Well my wcf service is the inprocess to windows service. It is installed on the my local p.c. and from the test/client project accesing the method.